# Numerical accuracy loss in Python

Tags: python, floating-accuracy, numerical

I wish to calculate the standard error of a series of numbers. Suppose the numbers are `x[i]` where i = 1 ... N. To do this

I set

```
averageX = 0.0
averageXSquared = 0.0
```

I then loop over all i=1,...N and for each I calculate

```
averageX += x[i]
averageXSquared += x[i]**2
```

I then divide by N

```
averageX = averageXC / N
averageXSquared = averageXSquared/N
```

I then take the square root of the difference

```
stdX = math.sqrt(averageXSquared - averageX * averageX)
```

The argument here is sure to always be >=0.

However if I set all `x[i] = 0.07` (for example) then I get a math domain error as the argument of the root function is negative. There seems to be some loss of precision.

The argument is of the order of 10e-15.

This does not look encouraging. I now have to check myself to see if the result is negative before taking the root.

Or have I done something wrong.

Comment: You will be lucky if `stdX = math.sqrt(averageXSquared - averageX * averageX)` is *always* positive. It will be very close to `0` as you said, but due to the intricacies of floating point math, it will not be exactly zero.

Comment: have you considered using [this](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.13.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.sem.html)

Comment: I'd recommend checking out the [Decimal](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html) module. You can manually set the amount of desired precision.

Comment: @AMacK I don't think it would help in this situation. You'd need infinite precision.

Comment: @MarkRansom For values on the order of 10e-15, wouldn't 30 digits of precision be sufficient?

Comment: @chepner given that the averages are taken by division there will always be some loss of precision. Depending on how the values are rounded to fit the available precision there's always the possibility of the two being unequal, no matter how many digits you provide. The "value" in this case is the accumulated error, not the expected result.

Answer (score 4):

This is not a python problem, but a problem with finite precision in general. If you set all numbers to the same value, the standard error is mathematically 0, but not for a computer. The correct way to handle this, is to set very small values <0 to 0.

```
x = [0.7, 0.7, 0.7]
average = sum(x) / len(x)
sqav = sum(y**2 for y in x) / len(x)
stderr = math.sqrt(max(sqav - average**2, 0))
```

Comment: That is a nice trick. It is worth mentioning that the _correct_ way (TIOOWTDI) is to use Numpy (if you can afford depending on it).

Answer (score 2):

The correct way, of course is never subtract large numbers. Have another pass, which guarantees non-negativity (you need to do some algebra to realize that the result *is* mathematically the same):

```
y = [ v - average for v in x ]
dev = sum(v*v for v in y) / len(x)
stderr = math.sqrt(dev)
```